# How can I create .ear with intellij ce?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Good day!

I want to create .ear file from intellij ce. I open the project structure settings, click artifacts, then click 'new' button. In Artifact page I cannot choose the ear artifact type.

If anyone knows about it please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [.ear file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) is just a .jar file with a predefined structure and some nested .jar files inside it. You can define that structure manually in the artifact configuration dialog.

Alternatively, you can write an Ant, Maven or Gradle build script (all of which are fully supported in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition) to build the .ear file for you.